# gmapping with turtlebot2 simulation does not create map

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello:

I am running ros indigo 32 on the Nootrix virtual machine. I am trying to make a map and navigate it with a turtlebot2 simulated robot, according to [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it).

In a terminal, I run `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch`

In another terminal, I run `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch`. It runs, but after a while, I get this message: *[ WARN] [1437734908.414750431, 97.100000000]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.*

In a third terminal, I run `roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch`. Rviz opens, and in Global Options, the fixed frame is set to map. The map element of rviz appears in yellow, with a "No map received" message.

If I open another terminal with `roslaunch kobuki_keyop keyop.launch`, the robot moves both in Gazebo and rviz, but in rviz there is no trace of the readings of the sensors; if I try to store the map with `rosrun map_server map_saver -f mymap`, I get a "Waiting for the map".

I have checked the tf tree with `rosrun tf view_frames`, and the tree seems to be completely connected (I am a newbie so it seems I cannot attach an image yet); at least the tree has a map -> odom -> basefootprint -> base_link path on it.I have made this source `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` in every terminal and before every roslaunch.

I have been googling and looking for help, but i can't find where the problem is. I would really appreciate any help you may offer.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Ana+

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214499/gmapping-with-turtlebot2-simulation-does-not-create-map/) by [ana+](https://answers.ros.org/users/23338/ana+/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-07-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ana+](https://answers.ros.org/users/23338/ana+/) on 2015-07-24**:
I tried [this](http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/28/) too, and again the same result.

I checked the /map topic (`rqt_graph`, `rosnode info slam_gmapping` / `rosnode info rviz`), and it's connected. But `rosrun tf tf_echo /map /odom` always return 0 values, even if the robot moves with kobuki node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I made it work with t[he solution to this different problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/210849/scan-message-must-contain-angles-from-x-to-x/).
I made [a complete report of the problem](http://jafma.net/ana/theweekendarchaeologist/?p=362), both in Spanish and English.

---

Originally posted by [ana+](https://answers.ros.org/users/23338/ana+/) with karma: 36 on 2015-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-03-05**:
I've got exactly the same situation as yours, and without your super detailed report I couldn't have solved the problem so quickly. Thank you so much！ :)

**Comment by [ana+](https://answers.ros.org/users/23338/ana+/) on 2016-03-15**:
Thank you for your kind comment :)

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2021-12-21**:
@ana+ will your solution work for ROS kinetic?